# Graphical view of files on server

Tags: samba, remote, file-manager

I work at a university, and I have a personal webpage. This is located in my home directory, under `public_html`. I want to start editing this webpage from Linux. Under Windows, I used to map to this network drive, by connecting to the server at `myserver.mydepartment.myuniversity.ac.uk`. This then gave me access to the `public_html` in Windows Explorer, which I could edit and add html files to.

How can I do a similar thing in Linux? The only way I have seen so far to get access to this folder is by using ssh: `ssh myserver.mydepartment.myuniversity.ac.uk`. From here, I can list the files in `public_html`. However, I want to see these files graphically, like in Windows Explorer, such that I can edit it them easily in a text editor. How can I do this in Linux (Ubunutu)?

Answer (score 1):

From `nautilus` (the file-manager) press <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to view the text address bar. In that bar type:

```
ssh://<your username>@myserver.mydepartment.myuniversity.ac.uk
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. `nautilus` should prompt for a password.

If everything works, you should see your server's files. You can bookmark the connection for future use.

Answer (score 0):

In Nautilus, which is the default Ubuntu file manager, use the menu “File” → “Connect to server”. In your setup, you have two choices:

- “Windows share” (Linux calls this [Samba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software))). Enter your Windows (usually, Active Directory) user name and password. The group is your Windows work group.
- “SSH”. This uses your SSH user name and password.